# Search a string in VBScript to verify if contains a character

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to see if a string contains a dot.

```
Set Root_Currency = Root_TaxDataSummary.SlvObject("Currency")   
curr_val = InStr(Root_Currency,".")
If curr_val.exist Then

     pass
else
     fail
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I am going about this?

Answer (score 6):

`InStr` [returns an integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c(v=vs.84).aspx) representing the position the searched text can be found in the string.

`curr_val.exist` won't work because the integer type doesn't have an `exist` method. Instead:

```
If curr_val > 0 Then
```

Or (if this is the only use of that variable):

```
If InStr(Root_Currency,".") > 0 Then
```

Lastly, because 0 is treated as False in VBScript, you don't need to include the inequality operator. Either a position is found for the character or you get back a 0/false:

```
If InStr(Root_Currency,".") Then
```

Answer (score 4):

[InStr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) returns a 'simple' number (1 based index/position of needle in haystack, or 0 meaning 'not found', or Null meaning Null argument) not an object. So change your code to:

```
If curr_val Then
   ' found
Else
   ' not found
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you can check:**

```
Dim MyString = "Hello world!"

If InStr(MyString, "H") > 0 Then
        wscript.echo "YES"
End If
```