# Searching a string in VBScript to verify words problem

Tags: vbscript

I'm slightly confused. I've written a small piece of a code that reads a string and outputs if the word is present in the string. The below code returns me 1 as expected

```
    Sub FindSomeText()
  MsgBox InStr("Look in this string", "Look")
End Sub
```

When i used the same logic on the below code but with a longer string i get a response of 16? instead of 1. Why would this be?

```
 Sub SearchAString()

  MsgBox InStr("Search through this random string and find how many strings are similar", "this")

End Sub
```

Comment: Yep, @OlivierDepriester is right and answered quicker than me. I can add a link for reference https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_instr.asp

Comment: Just return a boolean - `HasValue = (InStr("...", "...") > 0)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search a string in VBScript to verify if contains a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37168882/search-a-string-in-vbscript-to-verify-if-contains-a-character). Not the first time this has been covered, try searching via a search engine before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the string `this`. In the string `Search through this ...`, the term `this` starts on the 16th position. There is no issue with the way you use it.

`Instr` returns the position of the searched term and not a boolean saying if the term is present or not.

If the searched term is not found, `Instr` will return `0`

Comment: How would i change it so it returned 1 after it searched the string?

Comment: You can use ```Iif(Instr("....", ,"...) < 0, -1, 1)```. It is similar to ```If Instr("...", "...) < 0 Then result = -1 Else result = 1 End If ```

Comment: Suggest `HasValue = (InStr("...", "...") > 0)` is cleaner, that way you have a reusable boolean value. Also using `-1` and `1` for return values doesn't fit representation of a boolean in VBScript, which is `-1` for `True` and `0` for `False`.

Comment: Also, `InStr()` returns `0` not `-1` if the string is not found, so `> 0` is sufficient. - see [The Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//wybb344c%28v%3dvs.85%29).

Comment: @Lankymart My bad, I was stuck on this wrong idea. I have fixed my answer

Comment: No matter, it's been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37168882/search-a-string-in-vbscript-to-verify-if-contains-a-character).

Comment: Yes the above returns true or false if the word in the string. But what if from that string i want to specifically say how many times does the word 'Like' appear in a string.

Comment: @NewCoder Use a `For` loop *(`1` to `Len()` of the search string)* with `InStr()`, store the position returned by `InStr()` and keep track of how many times the word is found.

Comment: ```Instr``` has a ```start``` argument. Thus, you can loop on an ```Instr``` call until it returns 0. In the loop, each ```start``` value must be the previous ```Instr``` result + 1. so the first call will be ```Instr(1, "...", "this")``` and will return 16, next call will be ```Instr(17,"...", "this")```` ... and so on

Comment: I've written the following but it keeps returning 0 instead of 1   MyString = ("hello")
CharacterCount = Len(MyString) - Len(Replace(MyString, TargetCharacter, "hello")) 
MsgBox CharacterCount

Comment: @NewCoder like I said earlier, search - [Find all strings within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35244353)